# How would I normalize this table

Tags: database-design

How do I normalize the following table:

```
Table Order Detail:
-------------------
Order#
Item#
Desc
ShipDate1
Qty1
ShipDate2
Qty2
ShipDate3
Qty3
ShipDate4
Qty4
ShipDate5
Qty5
....
ShipDate20
Qty20
```

Comment: What do the Qty1, Qty2, Qty3 fields represent?

Comment: @liquorvicar S/B the quantity of each item being ordered for a given order number.

Comment: @Yuck But he has one Item id and twenty qty fields? Let alone normalising it that just doesn't work. I was wondering if something else is going on here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd want to have three tables: `Item`, `Order`, and `OrderDetail`:

```
OrderDetail: OrderId, ItemId, Quantity, ShipmentDate
Order: Id, ...
Item: Id, Desc, ...
```

A better way would be to separate the order detail from shipping detail:

```
OrderDetail: Id, OrderId, ItemId, Quantity
Order: Id, ...
Item: Id, Desc, ...
OrderShipment: Id, OrderDetailId, ShipmentDate, Quantity
```

`OrderDetail.Id` is a surrogate key for the table.  It's used again in the `OrderShipment.OrderDetailId` field. I've included `Quantity` on the `OrderShipment` table so that you can support partial order fulfillment.

The item description can be found by joining the `OrderDetail` and `Item` tables. You can get order header information by joining to the `Order` table.

In this design, you might have twenty records instead of that many columns:

```
OrderId ItemId Quantity
10      123    5
10      489    20
10      238    39
```

Comment: @Bruno The answer is still the same, with my minor edit for shipment date.

Answer (score 0):

Yuck's definition is a start.  I would add an Id for Order Detail as well in case the same item needs to appear on an order more than once (for instance, to accommodate pricing differences, delivery options, engraving, etc.).

I also found the question a little ambiguous, as quantities are repeated, but item is not.